# Technical chart analysis for stock maket

Tags: google-play, stock

What are the technical chart analysis sets that expert traders use for intraday trading (e.g. a set can be of RSI, moving average, and MACD)?

Answer (score 0):

One thing we must understand that every expert have there own set of rules. We need to find which technique is most suitable to us. Also each indicators have there own quality. For example Moving Averages are trend based indicator they fail when markets are sideways or RSI is a momentum indicator and it works when market are range bound. So it is very important to use indicators based on there characteristics.